# List of all objects in my Unity DI Container

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container

Is there a way to have a list of all objects registered in my DI Container.
ResolveAll gives a list for a type but I want a general list for all types

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can't get a list of all objects, because objects aren't registered, types are. Unity 2.0 added the UnityContainer.Registrations property you can use to look at what's in the container.

Be warned there's a known bug right now if you have open generics registered which causes the Registrations property to throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris
It looks like UnityContainer.Registrations is exactly what I need.
Why did I miss it?